# using the factory pattern with derived classes accepting diverse number of parameters

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I'm using the following [factory pattern:](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory)

```
using System;

class Program
{
    abstract class Position
    {
    public abstract string Title { get; }
    }

    class Manager : Position
    {
    public override string Title
    {
        get
        {
        return "Manager";
        }
    }
    }

    class Clerk : Position
    {
    public override string Title
    {
        get
        {
        return "Clerk";
        }
    }
    }

    class Programmer : Position
    {
    public override string Title
    {
        get
        {
        return "Programmer";
        }
    }
    }

    static class Factory
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Decides which class to instantiate.
    /// </summary>
    public static Position Get(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case 0:
            return new Manager();
        case 1:
        case 2:
            return new Clerk();
        case 3:
        default:
            return new Programmer();
        }
    }
```

The way to use this pattern is in the example from the same source:

```
static void Main()
{
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    var position = Factory.Get(i);
    Console.WriteLine("Where id = {0}, position = {1} ", i, position.Title);
}
}
```

**Should I be using this pattern if my derived classes are using different numbers of parameters for their constructors?**

The probable modification that I would need to make is when instantiating the factory:

```
var position = Factory.Get(i);
```

I would probably need to pass in parameters for all of the derived classes, regardless of whether they would use them or not:

```
var position = Factory.Get(i, param1, param2, param3);
```

and the switch statement would need to be modified:

```
public static Position Get(int id, param1, param2, param3) //HERE IS THE MODIFIED PARAM LIST
{
    switch (id)
    {
    case 0:
        return new Manager(param1); //MODIFIED
    case 1:
    case 2:
        return new Clerk(param2, param3); //MODIFIED
    case 3:
    default:
        return new Programmer(param3); //MODIFIED
    }
}
```

**Do the modifications that I've made to the factory pattern break the pattern, and should I be using a different pattern for object creation?**

Comment: Can you give more context about the consumer of the `Get` method? How does it get the parameter values?

Comment: Looks like an antipattern to me. If you need to know the params at the creation site, you already need to know what the ID means, so you get no benefit from having a single factory method to call. And what happens if the params are different for each constructor? You're going to have three separate sets of parameters, all passed to `Get()`? This looks bad.

Comment: The number of parameters in a constructor really doesn't matter.  it is just a convenience of initializing the class.  Some class have  lots of constructors while other have none (or a default from base class).

Comment: The client of the factory should not know of the Products dependencies. This means that the factory should not take in "how to create an object", but only "which object to create". If this does not suit your needs, you should look into the Builder pattern.

Comment: @jdweng thank you. could you show an example of how the classes would take in a default constructor from the base class in the context of the factory pattern?

Comment: @ChrisWohlert can you show an example please of how i can do that? ive been looking into how to form my code into something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/470476/Understanding-and-Implementing-Builder-Pattern-in but i am having trouble

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''', You already have a good example from the codeproject, but I am not sure that it is a builder you want. You use them for different reasons, and I'm not sure what your reasons are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a factory is to abstract the requirements of how to create an object so as to allow the client to ask for an object **without needing to know the details of how**.

One of the most classic uses of the pattern is having a app create a database connection based on a key that might return a MSSQL, SQLite, MySQL, etc, connection. The client doesn't care what the implementation is so long as it supports all of the required operations.

So the client should be completely agnostic to the parameters required.

Here's how to do it.

I've slightly expanded the `Position` classes:

```
abstract class Position
{
    public abstract string Title { get; }
}

class Manager : Position
{
    public Manager(string department) { }
    public override string Title => "Manager";
}

class Clerk : Position
{
    public override string Title => "Clerk";
}

class Programmer : Position
{
    public Programmer(string language) { }
    public override string Title => "Programmer";
}
```

Now I've created the `Factory` class like this:

```
static class Factory
{
    private static Dictionary<int, Func<Position>> _registry =
        new Dictionary<int, Func<Position>>();

    public static void Register(int id, Func<Position> factory)
    {
        _registry[id] = factory;
    }

    public static Position Get(int id)
    {
        return _registry[id].Invoke();
    }
}
```

Then it becomes easy to use the factory. When you're initializing the application you'd write this kind of code:

```
Factory.Register(1, () => new Manager("Sales"));
Factory.Register(2, () => new Clerk());
Factory.Register(3, () => new Programmer("C#"));
```

Now, later, when the client code wants a `Position` object it just needs to do this:

```
var position = Factory.Get(3);
```

In my testing when I output `position.Title` I got `Programmer` printed to the console.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer however I would like your opinion on whether you think this may be over engineered?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' - No, this isn't over engineered. This is precisely the thing you need to do if you want to abstract the creation of the objects from the code that consumes them. Do keep in mind that there are a ton of Inversion of Control/Dependency Injection frameworks out there that do this for you in a very powerful way. You should look at using them if your needs are anything more than basic.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. Could you recommend one of these Frameworks perhaps one that is easy to use?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' - I would look at this list - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx - I haven't used any of these extensively so I can't recommend. I wrote my own a few years back and used that all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The example is kind of too much dumbed down but yes, you can.

That said, this example may lead to some issues as the programmer may be confused as how to use the factory. For example, imagine that you have to define a GUI to create positions: does the GUI ask the user for all 3 `param` values, even if they make no sense for the position defined in the first place? If you answer "Yes" the user will be confused, if you answer "No" then the factory is not so much of a black box as it should be.

One example where I used this approach was for billing; my application billed the services of the same month to a lot of people in batch. Some people were charged by the number of natural days of the months, some people were charged by the number of laborable days. Since getting the laborable days was somewhat slow (it had to consult the DB for local and national holidays) I cached it and passed it to the instances that required it.

It was something like (Java):

```
public class BillerFactory {
  private HashMap<Date, ListOfHolidaysInMonth> holidayCache =
     new HashMap<>();

  ...

  public getBiller(BillingType billingType, Date firstOfMonth) {
    switch (billingType) {
      case BillingType.NATURAL:
         return new NaturalBiller(firstOfMonth);
      case BillingType.LABORAL:
         ListOfHoliday holidays = this.holidayCache.get(firstOfMonth);
         if (holidays == null) {
            holidays = this.calculateHolidays(firstOfMonth);
            holidayCache.put(firstOfMonth, holidays);
         }
         return new LaboralBiller(firstOfMonth, holidays);
       }
     }
```

TLDR: The issue is not that the constructor have different parameters but that in your example you are forcing the client to provide data that may not make sense.

Comment: great point!! "The issue is not that the constructor have different parameters but that in your example you are forcing the client to provide data that may not make sense."  --- could you recommend a different type of pattern for my use case?

Comment: You could extend the factory so it does not provide you the final instance, but the code that will finally provide the final instance. In the GUI example, it could provide you a JFrame subclass with the camps needed for each instance. That said, it begins to reek of overengineering so maybe it is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will use the default constructor in the Position class.

```css
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Manager mngr = new Manager();
        }
    }
    public abstract class Position
    {
        public abstract string Title { get; }
        public Position()
        {
        }
    }
    public class Manager : Position
    {
        public override string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return "Manager";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough context for me to suggest a good alternative, but your sample is not comfortable to use: idea of a factory pattern is to encapsulate object's creation, but since you have a different set of parameters for different objects, you have to know some differences between concrete implementations or you have to provide useless data every time. Maybe it's better just to use constructors?

Comment: you mean keep the pattern? but how would i pass information to each derived class?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' - I think he's saying the pattern isn't appropriate.

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' No, I mean don't use this pattern in this situation and just create your objects as usual.